# Dynamic options in Option tag using 'For loop' with html tags in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add dynamic options using For loop in javaScript using HTML tags.

I am trying to figure out better solution for below code :

```
html += '<label for="nameText" class="text-center control-label">SELECT TYPE : 
</label>' +'<select class="dropdown btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">' +'<option class="options dropdown-item" value = ' + types[0] + '>' + types[0].toUpperCase() + 
'</option>' +
'<option class="dropdown-item" value = ' + types[1] + '>' + types[1].toUpperCase() + '</option>' +
'<option class="dropdown-item" selected="selected" value = ' + types[2] + '>' + types[2].toUpperCase() + '</option>' +
'<option class="dropdown-item" value = ' + types[3] + '>' + types[3].toUpperCase() + '</option>' +
'</select>';
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: this isn't a code review...

Comment: This isn't code review , looking for solution

Comment: @jsBee — You are asking how to make working code "better". That's a code review. You haven't described a problem.

Comment: @jsBee If your code works, then this is a code review.  If it doesn't, then this is the place for your question, but you need to provide what exactly is wrong with it for us to start finding a fix.

Comment: The question asks how to create option elements in a loop. The code doesn't even come close to doing so. it isn't a code review. It is however likely a duplicate.

Comment: This is the reason ,I never prefer to ask question on Stackoverflow, I mentioned in quetion (edited more than 10 time to make sure I am not asking wrong question)

Comment: Is it possible to use a for loop in <select> in html? and how? : This question is related to HTML and I am asking related to JavaScript.

Comment: @jsBee The duplicate question has answers that show you how to do it directly in the html (using an inline script tag,) as well as the much better solution that does it using the proper dom api methods for creating/appending elements.

Comment: @Kevin B ,Before asking question I tried almost all solution, which was throwing error. my `var html` needs in `html tag` solution.

Comment: `//var selectTag = document.createElement("select");
            //var options = document.createElement("option");
            //for (var i = 0; i <= types.length; i++) {
            //   options.value = types[i];
            //   options.text = types[i];
            //    
            //}
            //selectTag.appendChild(options);` I tried this but it was not working and thats why I asked quetion in stackoverflow

Comment: You can use "String Interpolation" of ECMA6. Follow my example: https://codepen.io/b-i-thanh-dng/pen/LJrjpN

Comment: Thank you so much , You save my day. This is what I was looking for. I have one  question , How to make types[test2] selected by default?